# CUPS server problem - sending page correctly but no printing

Tags: server, printing, hp

I am new to Ubuntu, I searched for answer but with no luck. I have a HP LaserJet 1005 printer connected by USB interface to old HP laptop with Ubuntu Server 22.04 and CUPS. After installation and configuration I have a problem. Test page generator from web interface was sent to printer without error and job was completed but printer didn't do anything. My CUPS server is running as on the picture - `cups.path` is inactive I don't know if it is important.

CUPS status after start:
[image: CUPS status after start]

The `cupsd.conf` file is configured

```
Listen 192.168.8.15:631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
```

I used HP LaserJet Series PCL 6 CUPS
and URI path given by web interface : `usb://HP/LaserJet%20P1005?serial=BB0HZ40`. I also tried to add printer from terminal/command line also the same.

Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved - It is essential to install oryginal driver by installing hplip from repository and install the printer first.